# Why do I get undefined method `click' for Cucumber::Rails::World ? in Cucumber / Capybara steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I can get other capybara methods like visit, fill_in, select etc.. to work. but not **click**

```
Given /^a no fee license called "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  @l = FactoryGirl.create(:license,
                      name: arg1)
end

When /^execute the license$/ do
  visit(license_path(@l))
  click('Execute License')
end
```

error:

```
Scenario: no fee license is executed                                 # features/visitor_no_fee_license.feature:14
    When I fill out the licensee info with valid info                  # features/step_definitions/licenses_steps.rb:21
    And execute the license                                            # features/step_definitions/licenses_steps.rb:35
      undefined method `click' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x007feebad4dec8> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/licenses_steps.rb:37:in `/^execute the license$/'
      features/visitor_no_fee_license.feature:16:in `And execute the license'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Capybara's DSL changed. Use `click_on` instead of click, if you don't know if it's a link or a button now.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/549e67336c712a1ef2119ce5ff64dbbc7542480f/lib/capybara/session.rb

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to use [click_link](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3aclick_link)?

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end
```

There is also [click_button](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3aclick_button)

If neither of these suit your needs, then you can call [click](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element%3aclick) on an element.

```
When /^(?:|I )click "([^"]*)" span$/ do |selector|
  element ||= find('span', :text => selector)
  element.click
end
```

If none of the above is helpful, then here are a list of all the click methods, if you identify the one you wish to use, I may be able to assist further.

http://rubydoc.info/search/github/jnicklas/capybara/master?q=click

Comment: No, i wanted click because it can select a link or a button. but your second method is neat, thanks! I found the answer, posted below.